# Custom table cell without dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reusability, custom-cell

I have an averagely sized table which is working perfectly, except for the row insertion animation (`withRowAnimation`). I've overriden it (with the help of stack community) to have a longer duration than the original system animation and it works just fine, but ...

Because i'm using custom cells as reusable cells - each time i scroll this effect is getting wiped out.

So the only solution i see is to stop the reuse. 
I know this will interfere with the memory, but in this case its the only scenario left (of which i know).

My general question is how do i load a custom cell nib without using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` so that the reuse wouldn't happen.

Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

You should use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, not using it is a recipe for disaster.

Take a look into your code and when you dequeue a cell (reused or not, most of the time it'll be reused), the first thing you should do is set all elements in that cell back to the original state, so that that reused cell behaves like a non reused cell.

I don't know what you animation/implementation is about but here an example from a project I wrote with custom cells :

In each cell I added buttons, this could be 1, 2, 3,... buttons. If I did nothing in a reused cell I would have more buttons than expected because the old buttons would still be there...
So in my code the first thing I did after dequeing the cell would be to remove all the buttons.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RelatedCell") as! RelatedCell
cell.removeAllActionButtons()
```

where my removeAllActionButtons (a method in my custom cell) method would be something like:

```
for button in actionButtons {
    button.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

actionButtons is an Array containing all that buttons added to that custom cell

Comment: Didn't answer his question.